# How do I parse URL query via .htaccess with unknown number of preset parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need help with Apache's mod_rewrite rules.

I am very beginning with PHP and `.htaccess`. I am stuck trying to get user's query URL string, parse "language" and "page" as GET variables, pass them to `index.php` file in root, and respond to user with compiled webpage. Also I need my script correctly understand default language ("ee") and page ("index") values when one or both parameters in user's URL are not set. Examples:

```
1) "example.com/"           -->  "example.com/index.php?page=index&lang=ee"
2) "example.com/se/samples" -->  "example.com/index.php?page=samples&lang=se"
3) "example.com/se/"        -->  "example.com/index.php?page=index&lang=se"
4) "example.com/contact"    -->  "example.com/index.php?page=contact&lang=ee"
5) "example.com/ru/contact" -->  "example.com/index.php?page=contact&lang=ru"
```

I need Apache always show "clear URLs" only, like: `example.com/se/samples`. "Ugly URLs" with GET queries are for technical reasons only and *should not* be visible to users and/or search engines. I am also concerned with security issues, thus I am comfortable with using a white-list of manually set allowed parameters in `.htaccess` and/or `index.php`.

---

I have following website file structure on server side:

```
www:
|   .htaccess
|   __php__.php
|   index.php            <-- controller
|
+---css [...]
|
+---img [...]
|
+---js  [...]
|
+---lang                 <-- arrays of languages
|       lang_ee.json
|       lang_en.json
|       lang_ru.json
|       lang_se.json
|       sliders.json
|
\---tmpl                 <-- layout templates of pages
        contact.php
        footer.php
        header.php
        index.php
        nav.php
        retail.php
        samples.php
        services.php
```

---

I need following sitemap structure on front-end side:

```
lang=ee     page=index      example.com/
lang=ee     page=services   example.com/services
lang=ee     page=retail     example.com/retail
lang=ee     page=samples    example.com/samples
lang=ee     page=contact    example.com/contact

lang=en     page=index      example.com/en/
lang=en     page=services   example.com/en/services
lang=en     page=retail     example.com/en/retail
lang=en     page=samples    example.com/en/samples
lang=en     page=contact    example.com/en/contact

lang=ru     page=index      example.com/ru/
lang=ru     page=services   example.com/ru/services
lang=ru     page=retail     example.com/ru/retail
lang=ru     page=samples    example.com/ru/samples
lang=ru     page=contact    example.com/ru/contact

lang=se     page=index      example.com/se/
lang=se     page=services   example.com/se/services
lang=se     page=retail     example.com/se/retail
lang=se     page=samples    example.com/se/samples
lang=se     page=contact    example.com/se/contact
```

---

My current `index.php`:

```
<?php

      if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $page=$_GET['page'];
      } else {
        $page='index';
      }

      if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
        $lang=$_GET['lang'];
      }
      else { $lang='ee'; }


      // Include configs
      include('__php__.php');

      // Assign template
      include (ROOT_DIR.'tmpl/'.$page.'.php');

?>
```

---

My current `.htaccess` consists of several unlucky attempts:

```
# URLs rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

#RewriteRule ^(services|retail|samples|contact)/?$ $1.php [L]
#RewriteRule ^(index|services|retail|samples|contact)$ index.php?page=$1&lang=ee [L]
#RewriteRule ^([^/].*)([^/].*)$ index.php?page=$2&lang=$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^(en|ru|se)/(index|services|retail|samples|contact)$ index.php?page=$2&lang=$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^([^(en|ru|se)].*)/$ index.php?page=$1&lang=ee [N]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$2&lang=$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^(en|ru|se)/(services|retail|samples|contact)/?$ $1/$2.php [L]
#FFFFFUUU..
```

---

I have managed to make it work with one or two parameters set (e.g. `example.com/se/` or `example.com/se/contact`), but I am out of ideas where to dig further to make script universal. Pardon my rusty English.

**EDIT** 
I do only need my script to "listen to" following languages: `en`/`ru`/`se` and `ee` if not set; and pages: `services`, `retail`, `samples`, `contact` and `index` if not set. I still need `404` page on e.g. `example.com/blabla`. This is what I meant by "preset parameters" in question header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]{2}+)/?$ /index.php?page=index&lang=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]{2}+)/(.*)$ /index.php?page=$2&lang=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?page=index&lang=ee [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^((?!index.php).*)$ /index.php?page=$1&lang=ee [R=301,NC,L]
```

EDIT:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?page=index&lang=ee [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(services|retail|samples|contact)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&lang=ee [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(en|ru|se)/?$ /index.php?page=index&lang=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(en|ru|se)/(services|retail|samples|contact)?$ /index.php?page=$2&lang=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for response! I am now able to see pages, great. But there are two issues which don't meet my requirements: 1) URL in address bar is "uglified"; 2) even worse: this code hijacks **all** queries, e.g. this is how server interprets layout link to CSS-file: `/index.php?page=css/style.css&lang=ee` instead of `/css/style.css`. I do only need to "listen to" following languages: `en`/`ru`/`se` and `ee` if not set; and pages: `services`, `retail`, `samples`, `contact` and `index` if not set. I still need 404 page on e.g. `example.com/blabla`. This is what I meant by "preset parameters".

Comment: Isn't that community awesome? It works like a charm, thank you!